# Excel 2013 Crashes when Adding Userform in Visual Basic window

Tags: excel, crash, vba

I have a user who just got a new computer (Windows 10 Pro running Office 2013) and he can no longer open a macro enabled workbook.

I finally identified that the Userforms are causing the issue when I created a new workbook and added some VBA to it. Everything worked fine until I went to insert a Userform, that's when it crashed. I did some additional testing and found he can open .xlsm files except when a userform is in the VBA.

I looked into the References in the VBA window and checked the libraries, he seemed to have what he needed and I added anything I thought was missing but nothing helped.

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library (keeps unchecking itself but even when checked doesn't help)
- Ref Edit Control

What references could I be overlooking here?

The VBA code is not affecting it, I ran the opening code without any forms and it opened and enabled macros just fine.

What is preventing Excel from running a macro enabled workbook with userforms or adding a userform?

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit office? There are issues with userform controls in 64bit office

Comment: @HarassedDad 32 bit

Comment: I suspect "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" is the problem. That's c:\windows\system32\fm20.dll   . Why not check size and properties between this file on a machine where it works and the one where it fails.

Comment: @HarassedDad the version on the non-working computer (15.0.4737.1000) is older than on my working computer (16.0.4266.1001). Can I send my version of the file to the user to replace even if we are on two different windows versions (10 v. 7)?

Comment: You would need to unregister the old version and then register the new version - which would require that the user has admin privileges. The version of windows shouldn't affect the version number of office components, it's likely that the office installation didn't upgrade the dll and they have one left over from their previous version of office. Uninstalling and reinstalling office might be enough to fix it, but it depends on your IT infrastructure as to what privileges your user has,